# Accessing Listbox Results View in C#

Tags: c#

Hi there guys i am sure this is quite easy i am just completely new to C#.
So I can read the SQL database and bring back results but I cant figure out how to read the returning result which should then be inserted into the Database.

Any idea how I can read the Result View because i can see the value i want in there. Value for this example is 'AS'

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=###;Initial Catalog=######;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=##;Password=#######");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ISOCode from Countries Where CountryName like '" + CTRYLST.SelectedItem + "%'", con);
con.Open();

CTRYLST.Items.Clear();
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        CTRYLST.Items.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
    }
}
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CountryNoMail (ISOCode) VALUES ('" + CTRYLST.Items.ToString() + "');", con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: So all you want is the result of the sql command (cmd2)?

Comment: I just want CTRYLST.Items.ToString() to equal AS (Or whatever the query above brings back). It will only bring back one result at any point. The results are held in a Listbox.

Comment: CTRYLST.Items.ToString() Will give you the object description of the type (Which would be an ItemCollection). You would need to iterate through the Items collection and format the SQL to put those values in.

Comment: Could i do that using a loop?

Foreach (var item in collection)
{
      do something here
}

Comment: because the value i want is under results View > [0] can i do something like CTRYLST.Items.ResultsView[0]?

Comment: You can just do a CTRYLST.Items.Foreach(x => x.ToString())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sql is correct and everything is fine with the reading, eventually you can inspect the values at runtime by adding a break in the line of additems
You will be able top get back your values by using

```
CTRYLST.Items[0].ToString;
```

But it is always preferrable to use a for and cycle since you cannot be sure how many items there will be in the list box. Be careful that items are zerobased, so the first element has 0 as index, the first has 1 and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped